# Georeferencing JPEG from TIFF using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, georeferencing, geotiff-tiff, jpg

I recently georefernced some TIFFs. However, unfortunately I have to do the same stuff with equivalent JPGs (same image, same resolution, just JPGs).

Is there an easy way to georeference the JPGs using the TIFFs using ArcMap 10.3?

Comment: If the JPEG images are *exactly* the same you can copy and rename the TFW files to JGW files; however I like the answer by Mr Che, it's straightforward and batchable.

Comment: How did you georeference your tiffs? Did you need to measure ground control points?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  By originally asking how to do the same thing in either of three products you were effectively asking three questions which would have made this too broad.  I removed the two products for which there were no answers yet.  You can always ask about the other two in separate questions.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Copy Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm) tool to convert georeferenced tiffs to jpeg format.

Comment: I think a one line answer is appropriate here.  It is very much to the point.